# Sanitizing user inputs with Spring MVC framework

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, xss, sql-injection

I am working on web application using spring mvc framework, I wanted to know is there any best way to sanitize user inputs or common method to sanitize all the user inputs in springs to avoid XSS and Sql Injection attacks?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `Filters` in Spring framework to clean your forms. Filters will fetch all your request attributes and clean them all before processing the request. Another option is to use `JSoup` API's. visit following links to know more.

[JSoup XSS Api's](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer)

[Filter approach to prevent XSS threat](http://jeevanpatil.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/prevention_of_xss/)

**EDIT :**

Read OWASP sheets to know how to avoid XSS and SQL injection.

[OWASP - prevention of XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)

[OWASP - prevention of SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java)

Take a look at [HDIV](http://hdiv.org/) which integrates with spring 3.1, it has out-of-the-box support for XSS, CSRF, Data Integrity Checks.

Comment: thank for the answer! But still it does not completely satisfies my requirement!

Comment: If you need better & different approach than this, let me do a search for you.

Comment: Thanks alot for spending your valuable time for answering my question!

Comment: Really liked the filter approach, thanks for answering. :)

Comment: @JeevanPatil웃 The filter approcah handles the RequestParam values. How to hanlde RequestBody values too?

Comment: For the XSS filter approach above (Filter approach to prevent XSS threat), don't forget to override getParameterMap() method in your HttpServletRequestWrapper implementation.            How? The implementation is kinda similar to the one in getParameterValues(...) method. You should sanitize each parameter value (String[] values).            Why? Depending to the technology you use, getParameterMap() might be called to initialize the parameters in your controller.