# Spring MVC Validating all parameters in POST/PUT methods in controllers

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, xss

I have plenty of controllers and I want to validate all of parameters submitted in forms against XSS attacks. Instead securing each controller separately I would like to have one component that works as interceptor for all submitted forms and checks the parameters submitted.

I wrote a Filter that uses antisamy for correcting values of parameters but it works too good. I mean it escapes everything, even rich content that should not be escaped.
[Sanitizing user inputs with Spring MVC framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653448/sanitizing-user-inputs-with-spring-mvc-framework)
https://jeevanpatil.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/prevention_of_xss/

Therefre I need some solution to escape concrete parameters in controlers, do u know any solution ? I plan to create annotation next to parameters in every method in controller, for example @XSSEscaped, then only those parameters would be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

HTML encoding at the time of input can corrupt the data. It may still not be secure because data inserted into an attribute, stylesheet, or script could still execute code even with HTML encoding. It may not cover all the data on the page as some values might not have come through the controller, or could have been modified since then.

There are many ways to bypass input filters (see [XSS Filter evasion cheatsheet](https://owasp.org/www-community/xss-filter-evasion-cheatsheet)). The `RequestWrapper` in the linked answer for example filters out `eval()`, but pass in `e<script></script>val()` instead and you get `eval()` as output again. Fix that, then they'll be something else.

HTML encoding is the the responsibility of the view layer. This is where you can make sure all the data used on the page is encoded appropriately for the context where it's used. XSS is prevented by following the rules at the [Cross Site Scripting Prevention Cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). Templating systems like Thymeleaf will do HTML encoding by default of its values.